# How can I get "primed TNT" in my inventory?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way I can make it so when I place an item it places primed TNT (flashing TNT that is about to explode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use some command tricks to do it, but it's actually pretty simple to pull off.

First, pick a spawn egg. Any spawn egg will work but I wouldn't choose: Withers, Ender Dragons, Spiders, or cave spiders. (The bosses are obvious, but the reason I wouldn't choose the spiders is because when they are invisible their eyes still glow.) I will choose mooshrooms because the spawn egg's color scheme looks like TNT's.

Next make a *repeating, always active, unconditional* command block that says:

```
effect @e[type=mooshroom,name="Primed TNT"] invisibility 99999 0 true
```

This makes them invisible so it will hide the death animation. Next, in a *chain, always active, conditional* command block say:

```
execute @e[type=mooshroom,name="Primed TNT"] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt
```

This summons TNT. Next, a *chain, always active, conditional* command block that says:

```
kill @e[type=mooshroom,name="Primed TNT"]
```

This kills the mooshroom effectively replacing it with the TNT.

Now rename a spawn egg `Primed TNT` in an anvil and place it down and you have TNT! You can change the name to anything and you can even include formatting codes ( `§` ), just make sure you exchange the names in the command blocks for something *exactly the same, including the formatting codes.*

Comment: All that is left is to make a texture pack. Nice.